# What is the difference between Lazarus and CodeTyphon

Tags: ide, comparison, lazarus, fpc, codetyphon

Firstly, I saw some topics about these two but weren't my answer.

I'm looking for a good FPC(Free Pascal Compiler) IDE on GNU/Linux.

There are some IDE's like [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) and [CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon). I need suggestion to choose one of those.

I've tried Lazarus once but all windows was separated. It looks messy and not interesting.

I would like to know what are the distinguishes between these two ?

I would like to know advantages / disadvantages each of those. Thank you

Comment: Using **Glass docking** from **CT** in **Lazarus** can make **Lazarus** look the way you want (http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/forum/general-discussions/2625-giving-glassdocking-a-second-chance#4574). Using **FPCUP** can help you install/update/maintain several **Lazarus** versions (like FPC 2.6.2 + Laz Trunk, or FPC 2.7.1 + Laz 1.0.12, or FPC Trunk + Laz Trunk...). **FPCUP** can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/reiniero/fpcup

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CodeTyphon is a distro of Lazarus, like Ubuntu and Debian are distros of Linux.

CodeTyphon comes with a large package of components and plugins, that otherwise you would have to google and download and install.

CodeTyphon have their own idea what are stable versions and what are not stable yet for both of FPC (compiler) and Lazarus(IDE). Whether their assessment is better or worse than upstream's Lazarus Team's, I don't know.

What about one-single-window plugin, it is work-in-progress and it doesn't seems to me it is ready for production use, no matter would you get it as part of CT or download and add it to vanilla Lazarus. However maybe it better works on Linux than on Windows, I don't know.

There were however issues with code legality in CT grande bundle. It is widely believed that Orca (if I remember the name) violates copyrights of glScene/vgScene, which also happened in early Delphi FMX releases but was fixed by EMBA later. There also were disputes in FPC forums/wiki about CodeTyphon pirating some open-source components. See answer by Peter Dunne below.

Comment: +1 from my limited experience, Code Typhon is what made Lazarus + FPC usable. I couldn't get anything working prior to that.

Comment: Basically Code Typhon only prepares crosscompiling and a bunch of externally sourced components. Normal Lazarus Windows installers work out of the box, and have for years

Answer (score 7):

Your question is akin to asking the difference between Linux and Ubuntu. Lazarus is an IDE/component library, based on FreePascal (FPC). And CodeTyphon is a distribution of Lazarus and FPC. So CodeTyphon is just one way to install a functioning installation of Lazarus.

Lazarus uses the same floating window design as older versions of Delphi. Installing from CodeTyphon won't change that.

Comment: CT has an experimental plugin to convert IDE into single-window design. Which, of course, can be installed into vanilla Laz as well. Hardly usable though.

Comment: @HamedKamrava dunno, it is just already there in CT. Perhaps Anchor Docking? see https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=lazarus+single+ide+window&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

Comment: @arioch  I could not understand that part of your answer. I get it now.

Comment: @HamedKamrava it is actually called pl_GlassDocking, in order to use it you should drag the seperate window using the line at the side of the window (its color is light yellow by default) and you will see that you can attach two window together with it.

Comment: @HamedKamrava, For combining lazarus windows, you can install "KZ Desktop" plugin in Lazarus. Please look at this: http://www.raphaelz.com.br/

Answer (score 5):

Myself and several friends highlighted several licensing issues with codetyphon
most of which could have been corrected by sourcing the included files from known good source and ensuring the correct license headers were included
PirateLogic refused to correct the issues which means they are using code in direct violation of the original license terms
The fact its open source code does not change the fact they are pirating the code by not including the correct license even after the issue was highlighted
I also found several instances of copyright code included which appears to be proprietary and not FOSS at all
They also changed the path & file names on some libraries so that source is no longer compatible with standard lazarus/component installs
This in my view is totally illogical
These 2 factors heavily undermine what was potentially the best FPC/Lazarus distro
Hardly professional

Answer (score 2):

Lazarus can be a daunting installation process due to it's nature as a cross compiling environment. You don't just download an installer and click ok. A typical "installation" is actually a bootstrap FPC compiler doing a three-pass compilation of an "install". There are plenty of good installation scripts/methods from the official Lazarus/FPC team and in the community for a . But, understandably, the installation process is a skill in itself.

CodeTyphon is a a different/separate branch of an installer system, which is more of a utility suite/tools/third party code compilation library. If you want the simplest installation experience go with CodeTyphon. It has the nice graphical front end for managing the compiler. You can conveniently do the fancy stuff like build "cross-compilers" for almost every "target" operating system out there. It also is jam packed with hundreds of the best components/libraries pre-installed. It is a very actively maintained project and very professional. A whole lot of work is done for you.

Even if you want to be learn the low level compiler capabilities, CodeTyphon is a good place to start. It is written in FCP/Lazarus and is open source. Simply study it as "working demo app" and the other info on the compiler details. If you crash it, at least you don't have to learn to climb the hill. You get to get to start from the top and lose control on the way down. Start from scratch (and a three hour reinstallation) Hahaha

Comment: Note that daunting only for /cross/ purposes. Normal Lazarus installers on target (and also win32->win64) are pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Lazarus also has a package "AnchorDock" which allows you to dock all the windows into one. Either install the anchor dock design package after installing Lazarus, or install Lazarus using the script at getlazarus.org which will do it for you.